# Memory optimization of a small class in C#

Tags: c#, memory, optimization

I have a piece of code that turns a large matrix of strings into a large matrix of `MyClass`. `MyClass` is a small class I wrote that stores some information about each string and looks like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyEnum Class { get; private set; }

    public int A { get; private set; }
    public int B { get; private set; }
    public int C { get; private set; }
    public int D { get; private set; }
}
```

At present the software is able to handle matrices as large as 5-20 columns by 1 million rows, but I would like to increase the row count up to closer to 10 million. I don't believe there is much I can do to reduce the footprint of the string matrix but I would like to reduce the memory footprint of `MyClass`.

I can use `short` as the type of column `A` and `byte` as the type of `B`, `C` and `D`, though this will require quite a large refactor of the code.

My question, or rather questions:

1. Is it worth refactoring the code to use `short` and `byte`?
2. Should I also refactor `MyEnum` to be of type `byte`?
3. Is there anything else I can do to make the class more efficient?

Many thanks for your time!

Edit: a little more context - the matrix of `MyClass` is created from the matrix of strings for the purpose of analysis. The matrix of strings is pulled out of a text file over a mediocre network connection, so splitting the task into smaller chunks is not ideal.

Comment: Do you really need to store all this data in memory at the same time?

Comment: I must confess I hadn't given the option of splitting the task down enough serious thought @DanielRenshaw - thanks for making me think it through more thoroughly! In the event, it's not ideal for my problem.

Comment: Just a random, out of the box idea, but could you use [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) to do whatever you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Consider making it a struct instead of a class.

Comment: LogParser isn't quite what I need - the tool has to deal with a variety of unusual structured text formats on the fly, without prior knowledge of the file's schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now, assuming that all of your properties are implemented by instance variables, and that you run on a 64bit machine, instance of MyClass is 4B*4 + 8B = 24B.
Moreover, since you're using a class (reference type), the matrix of MyClass will have a further weight of 8B per cell. Which means you are using 32B per cell. Then, a 10Mx20 matrix of MyClass uses about 6.4GB (with these sizes, you must necessarily use a 64 bit binary), it may be more than that, because I'm ignoring memory alignment requirements.

If you switch from a class to a struct (value type), the matrix will directly store MyClass instances, rather than pointers to MyClass instances. So, you will save 8B per instance.
Now, the memory usage goes down to 4.8GB.

If you further tune your instance variables, by using 1 short and 3 bytes, and turn the enum to byte, each instance will use only 6B. So, the total memory usage will drop to 1.2GB.

Anyway, it will be more than that, because the managed environment stores some other metadata in each object, and because memory alignment requires objects to be padded for faster access times.

PS: you don't actually need to change the return type of your properties. You can encapsulate the type change, and perform casts in the implementation of MyClass, like:

```
struct MyClass
{
  private short a; //Also consider ushort, if you need it
  //...

  public int A
  {
    get { return a; //Automatic promotion }
    private set
    {
      a = (short) value;
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(a == value, "Integer overflow");
    }
  }

  //...
}
```

this way, the optimization will be transparent to the code that uses MyClass.

Comment: Remember, though, the 2GB limit on individual objects. Changing to a `struct` results in an array that's 4.8 GB in size, which couldn't be represented in a single object before .NET 4.5 and [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054.aspx)

Comment: I really like the approach here in that it allows me to avoid refactoring other aspects of the code base, but given that we're dealing with millions of operations, does the casting come with a performance penalty?

Comment: @Root_Kabal A type casting is a single machine instruction on most architectures, and the ALUs always work in 32 bit or 64 bit precision, so they would be converted to int anyway, at a certain point. Most of the overhead will be due to the more complex load and store instructions that will be needed to actually work with MyClass objects, rather than to type casting.

Comment: @Root_Kabal: If you use readonly fields as I showed, there is no need for a setter, so there's no need for casting. And the automatic promotion of `short` to `int` costs nothing.

Comment: Thanks @JimMischel, I missed your point on readonly fields - I'm from a Java background and wasn't aware such a useful thing existed! As it happens, the performance impact was non-existent using either your or Giulio's approach.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot you can do to reduce the size of a string matrix, depending of course on what the strings contain. If you have many duplicated strings, you can use [string interning](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/08/understanding-c-stringintern-m.html) or [build a string pool](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=711).

If your strings aren't duplicated but are typically ASCII or some other single-byte encoding (or UTF-8 with a majority of single-byte characters), you can save a lot of memory by [building a string resource table](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=833). See [Reducing memory required for strings](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=832) for an introduction.

For your `MyClass`, you're paying a per-instance allocation overhead of 16 bytes, which is almost as much as the data itself occupies. I would recommend making it a `struct` if the members are all immutable. They appear to be *publically* immutable. What you do privately, I don't know. But something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
struct MyStruct
{
    public readonly MyEnum Class;
    public readonly int A;
    public readonly int B;
    public readonly int C;
    public readonly int D;

    public MyStruct(MyEnum cls, int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        Class = cls;
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
        D = d;
    }
}
```

Results in a total of 20 bytes per instance with no per-instance allocation overhead. So your 10 million rows by 20 columns would be (10M * 20 * 20), or about 4 gigabytes. In .NET 4.5, you can use the [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054.aspx) configuration setting to create an array that large.

Be aware, though, that you might run into performance issues. Consider this code:

```
MyStruct m = MyArray[x,y];
// now access fields of m
```

With a struct, that *makes a copy* of the item at `MyArray[x,y]`. That means copying 20 bytes. It also means that if you modify `m.A`, that change won't be reflected in the array. You'd either have to copy it back (i.e. `MyArray[x,y] = m;`) or forego the intermediate variable altogether and write `MyArray[x,y].A = 5;`

Of course if your structures are immutable, you don't have the copy-back problem.

It *is* possible to work with large numbers of items in memory with C#, but you have to be creative with how you do it. I've found that using structures in this way is quite effective, especially if they're immutable.

Comment: Lots of useful string optimization reading for me - thanks! At a glance, I fear that for this particular problem they won't have a huge impact, as the input files to the problem will have hugely varying rates of duplication, and could come in any number of encodings.

MyClass is indeed immutable though, and so is a good candidate to be turned into a struct which along with the other changes suggested should bring me significantly closer to my goal.

Comment: @Root_Kabal: Look carefully at your string encodings. If they're predominantly single-byte encodings (or UTF-8 with a majority of single-byte characters), the string resource table can still save you a lot of space.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to set a defined limit for the size of the matrix which has to cover any type of string that the software may encounter. Whilst most of the time it'll be ASCII, there will definitely be occasions when UTF16 strings need to be processed - meaning my limit will have to accommodate the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 1):

[short](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx) is 16 bits

[int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5kzh1b5w.aspx) is 32 bits

you can set the size of your Enum without any real work as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

```
enum Days : byte {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

That means you can reduce the size of your class by half.
If that is good enough for the amount of work - that is up to you

Comment: In this case it probably doesn't matter as the storage for the enum will be padded.

Answer (score 0):

IN terms of making Your class smaller, Your assimptions to use other datatypes are right.
This will reduce the entire memory amount allocated.
In terms of data-presentation in memory You seem to create some kind of hana, Do You ?
If this is the case, there are other optimizations, mainly referred to as references to collections, meaning, You are not storing real values inside each column  You are storing references to other values which belong to a dictionary with unique entries.
Furthermore You must align Your data in another way. Do not think row orientated but switch to column orientated data-presentation in memory ( or at least in Your brain ).

These are techniques used by SAP hana to keep huge amnounts of data in memory rather then on hd.

Answer (score 0):

If you use classes, a gain could be obtained by creating n subclasses of `MyClass`, one for each value of `MyEnum` (this if `MyEnum` has a discrete quantity of values) and then removing `MyEnum`.

This would work only if `MyClass` is a class clearly.